# Nested partial object defaults when destructuring in JS?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Consider the following code:

```
function foo({
    item1 = 'a',
    item2 = 'b',
    item3 = {x: 1, y: 2}
} = {}) {
    console.log(item1,item2,item3.x,item3.y)
}
```

If you call `foo()` you will get an object with the defaults for item1, item2, and item3.  You can also call `foo({item1: 'm', item2: 'n'})` and your result will include the default `item3` of `{x: 1, y: 2}`.  However, if you call:

```
foo({item1: 'm', item2: 'n', item3: {x: 99}})
```

you'll get `undefined` for `item3.y` in the scope of the function `foo`.

**So:**

Is there a way to get individual defaults for the nested properties of `item3` in a scenario such as this?

Comment: In exactly the same way that you did define individual defaults for the `item1`, `item2` and `item3` properties of your argument object, to which you assigned the default `{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

In the parameters, you're trying to extract 3 variables: an `item1` object, an `item2` object, and an `item3` object.

On top of that, you're also trying to *mutate* the `item3` object in case it doesn't contain a certain property.

But all destructuring can do is extract properties from an object into variables - it cannot *mutate* any existing objects (without some really ugly wacky code that shouldn't be used).

If you're OK extracting the *individual properties* of `item3` into new variables, it would be quite possible, though:

```js
function foo({
  item1 = 'a',
  item2 = 'b',
  item3: {
    x = 1,
    y = 2
  } = {}
} = {}) {
  console.log(item1, item2, x, y)
}


foo({item1: 'm', item2: 'n'})
foo({item1: 'm', item2: 'n', item3: {x: 99}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The solution is to destruct more.
From:

```
function foo({
    item1 = 'a',
    item2 = 'b',
    item3 = {x: 1, y: 2}
} = {}) {
    console.log(item1,item2,item3.x,item3.y)
}
```

to

```
function foo({
    item1 = 'a',
    item2 = 'b',
    item3: {x = 1, y = 2} = {},
} = {}) {
    console.log(item1,item2,x,y)
}
```

Sadly existence of `item3` must be removed and only `x` and `y` can be used.

The another solution can be only `item3 = Object.assign({x: 1, y: 2}, item3)` as the first line of `foo`'s body.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hackish way to achieve something very close. You can declare a property that won't appear it the original object (`item3ex`), and then use the original property (`item3`) to override the defaults with object spread.

```js
function foo({
  item1 = 'a',
  item2 = 'b',
  item3,
  item3ex = { x: 1, y: 2, ...item3 } 
} = {}) {
  console.log(item1, item2, item3ex)
}

foo({item1: 'm', item2: 'n'})
foo({item1: 'm', item2: 'n', item3: {x: 99}})
```